# multiple encrypted EBS volumes and LVM

Tags: lvm, amazon-ec2, disk-encryption, aws

I would like to use encrypted EBS volumes to setup LVM partition for an EC2 instance.
According to the documentation, encryption is transparent for EC2 instance, but I'm concerned about multiple encrypted EBS volumes in one LVM volume group. 
Let's say, I start with one encrypted EBS volume in volume group and want to add more ebs volumes later. Would it work?
Or is safer to use non-encrypted EBS and setup LUKS on top of LVM?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that from Linux's perspective EBS volumes are just block devices, you can in fact go either way: LVM on top of LUKS or LUKS on top of LVM.

Your concern is certainly a valid one; LVM on LUKS is a bit complex. See [dm-crypt/Encrypting an entire system - LVM on LUKS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS) in the ArchWiki.

LUKS on top of LVM does simply things. In addition, it allows you to have unencrypted and encrypted LVM logical volumes simultaneously, and you can add more PE (physical extents) backed by EBS volumes into the same one volume group.